# How to insert data in 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have 2 tables 'userlogin' and 'user' and then 1 have a form which is 1 form inserting into 2 tables, so far i manage to insert the data but when it has to do with "primary key" and "foreign key" it has problem, as u can see from code below id_login from table userlogin is a primary key and id_login from table user is a foreign key the problem is when i inserting the data, id_login from userlogin has it value while in table user it has no value, below are my code, is there any simple way or am i doing something wrong?

**Controller**

```
function add()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama Lengkap','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('jenis_user','Jenis User','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat','alamat','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hp','hp','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username',TRUE);

        $params = array(
            'nama'       => $this->input->post('nama',TRUE),
            'username'   => $this->input->post('nama',TRUE),
            'password'   => md5($this->input->post('password',TRUE)),
            'jenis_user' => $this->input->post('jenis_user',TRUE),
            'alamat'     => $this->input->post('alamat',TRUE),
            'hp'         => $this->input->post('hp',TRUE),
            'email'      => $this->input->post('email',TRUE),
        );

        if($this->Admin_model->cek_username($username)){
            if($this->Admin_model->user_daftar($username,$params))
            {
                set_header_message('success','Tambah Pengguna','Berhasil menambahkan pengguna');
                redirect(base_url(akses().'/pengguna'));
            } else {
                set_header_message('danger','Tambah Pengguna','Gagal menambahkan pengguna');
                redirect(base_url(akses().'/pengguna/add'));
            }
        } else {
            set_header_message('danger','Oops.. Maaf','Username sudah ada yang menggunakan');
            redirect(base_url(akses().'/pengguna/add'));
        }

    } else {
        $meta['judul']="Tambah Pengguna";
        $this->load->view('tema/header',$meta);     
        $d['jenis_user']=$this->Admin_model->user_akses_data();
        $this->load->view(akses().'/pengguna/penggunaadd',$d);
        $this->load->view('tema/footer');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function user_daftar($username,$params)
{   
    if($this->db->insert('userlogin', $params)) {
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: if table field is same tha you use in model :-    if($this->db->insert('userlogin', $params)) {
$this->db->insert('tablename', $params)
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }

Comment: This question, and any you post here, would benefit from replacing "u" with "you", and "i" with "I".

Answer (score 1):

Use two different arrays and two different functions in model to insert different data in two different tables.

Comment: I suggest you should elaborate your answer as @addisalem. This ain't helping community users.

Comment: I just give an idea. Thanks for suggestion. I will try next time to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will work, if same data for both tables otherwise you need to make two arrays.

```html
 function user_daftar($username,$params)
{   
    if($this->db->insert("userlogin", $params)) {
        $id_login=$this->db->insert_id(); // user login id
  $params["id_login"]=$id_login;
  $this->db->insert("user", $params); 
  
  return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first separate the data if based on Table attribute then pass two the model

```
 $params = array(
            'nama'       => $this->input->post('nama',TRUE),
            'username'   => $this->input->post('nama',TRUE),
            'password'   => md5($this->input->post('password',TRUE)),

        );
 $params2 = array(
          'jenis_user' => $this->input->post('jenis_user',TRUE),
            'alamat'     => $this->input->post('alamat',TRUE),
            'hp'         => $this->input->post('hp',TRUE),
            'email'      => $this->input->post('email',TRUE),

        );

$this->Admin_model->modelXXX($$params1,$params2)
```

one function on the model side with two param but one thing you have to consider that first, insert a data to the reference table   $id_login=$this->db->insert_id(); then insert the second table

```
 function modelXXX($params1,$params2)
{   
    if($this->db->insert("userlogin", $params1)) {
        $id_login=$this->db->insert_id(); // user login id
        $params["id_login"]=$id_login;
        $this->db->insert("user", $params2); 

        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: my table database like this